# Codec which supports intra-frame

Tags: video, codec, encoder, decoder, virtualdub

I'm using VirtualDub and I want to digitalize a VHS movie frame by frame.
But I need a codec which supports intra-frames.

Do the following codecs supports intra-frame?

[image]

If not where can I get or buy a codec with intra-frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your current choices:
Lagarith may be ok
Xvid can be set to intra mode but this is somewhat pointless.
There is a lot of better free codecs.
utvideo and magicyuv are excellent lossless intra codecs.
cineform is very good lossy intra codec but somewhat more difficult to install.

Comment: I'm now using utvideo codec for VirtualDub, but intra-frames don't work. What should I set to capture a video frame by frame?