# Intra Frame Settings for UtVideo Codec in VirtualDub

Tags: codec, virtualdub

In my previous question I'd asked for a convenient codec which supports intra frames and prevents onion skin animation. Now I'm using the UtVideo codec.

[Codec which supports intra-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625732/codec-which-supports-intra-frame/40649902#40649902)

[image]

Which UtVideo version shall I use?

[image]

And how get I the right setting for capturing a video frame by frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variants are good but correspond to different YUV matrix/sampling: normally you should know what your capture source is and select the same.

If you capture screen there should be UtVideo RGB option, not sure why you dont have it. Try latest installer http://umezawa.dyndns.info/wordpress/?p=6107

Comment: My capture source is a video grapper which is connected with a S-VHS player.